# Spacy NER - Train a model only having a collection of entities

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, spacy

I have a database with a collection of thousands of products and we are working on a NLP module on our system that should be capable of read text and identify all the products from it.

The problem is: We have many entities to be tagged but we don't have enough samples to train the model. So what we are doing is just to generate some random text and adding those entities like this:

```
Training_data = [
    ("I'm looking for the P1.\n", {'entities': [(20, 22, 'Product')]}),
    ('I bought P2 last week.\n', {'entities': [(9, 11, 'Product')]}),
    ('P1 is better than P2.', {'entities': [(0, 2, 'Product'), (18, 20, 'Product')]})
]
```

I'm struggling to find a way to just pass a collection with all of our products to perform the spacy training. Is this possible? Any better solution or approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makers of spaCy have stated that you will need 5,000 examples to be able to see some sort of results. spaCy 2 is a tad lower at 500 - 1000 but your mileage will vary.

To provide training examples to the entity recogniser, you'll first need to create an instance of the GoldParse class. You can specify your annotations in a stand-off format or as token tags.

```py
import spacy
import random
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.language import EntityRecognizer

train_data = [
    ('Who is Chaka Khan?', [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')])
]

nlp = spacy.load('en', entity=False, parser=False)
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=['PERSON', 'LOC'])

for itn in range(5):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in train_data:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)

        nlp.tagger(doc)
        ner.update(doc, gold)
ner.model.end_training()
```

Or you can try this instead:

```py
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, [u'rats', u'make', u'good', u'pets'])
gold = GoldParse(doc, [u'U-ANIMAL', u'O', u'O', u'O'])
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=['ANIMAL'])
ner.update(doc, gold)
```